# How correct use generics?

Tags: typescript

There is a set of interfaces:

```
export interface FormData<T extends ControlData = any> {
  [type: string]: T;
}

export type FormResult<T extends FormData> = {
  [type in keyof T]: T[type];
};

export interface ControlData<T = any> {
  value: T;
}

export interface ButtonSelectControlData<T> extends ControlData<T> {
  query: string;
}

export interface RoutesAddCityData extends FormData {
  cityId: ButtonSelectControlData<number>;
  routeId: ControlData<number>;
}
```

When I use FormResult:

```
(data: FormResult<RoutesAddCityData>) => {
  // ...
}
```

As expected I see in IDE that `data.cityId` has type `ButtonSelectControlData<number>` and `data.routeId` has type `ControlData<number>`. 
But I would like to see type number in both cases. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I would like to see type number in both cases"*? Neither of the two objects are of type `number`, they just contain members of type `number`

Comment: I need rewrite somehow FormResult to see ```data.cityId: number``` and ```data.routeId: number``` instead of ```ButtonSelectControlData<number>```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `FormResult` type to extract the underlying type parameters from `ButtonSelectControlData` and `ControlData`. If that's the case, then one possible solution is to create a *conditional type*:

```
type FormResult<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ControlData<infer U>
    ? U
    : never         
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I have never work with ```inver``` keyword. Your solution is good for two classes. But it's possible that in future another children of ```ControlData``` or ```ButtonSelectControlData``` will be added.

Comment: I tried to simplify your code 
```export type FormResult<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ControlData<infer U> ? U : never;
};``` 
and it works as well.

Comment: Yes, it will work because `ButtonSelectControlData` doesn't really use its parameter type — it only passes it to `ControlData`.